# Splitting field using a SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table with field "comments" with 100 characters or less. I want to divide this field into a batch of 20 characters each and then add a delimiter after each batch of 20. The text within the field doesn't have any delimiter that can be used. I am able to do this for the first 20 letters using substring but not for the rest. Can someone please suggest a SQL query  for doing this?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what the holy god have you tried?

Comment: I tried using substring. I am able to do it one time i.e. the first 20 but not after that.

Comment: Hi! Please see my answer below.. It will parse your field up to the maximum capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try using user defined function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitBy(
@String varchar(max),
@Delimiter char(1)
)
returns varchar(max)
as     
begin

declare @fldSize int
    set @fldSize = 20
declare @TotalCnt int
    set @TotalCnt = len(@String)
declare @c int
    set @c = 1

declare @TS varchar(max)
    set @TS = ''

if @TotalCnt > @fldSize begin

    set @TS = substring(@String, @c, @fldSize)
    set @c = @c + @fldSize

    while @c < @TotalCnt begin
        set @TS = @TS + @Delimiter + substring(@String, @c, @fldSize)
        set @c = @c + @fldSize
    end
    if @c = @TotalCnt begin
    set @TS =  @TS + @Delimiter + substring(@String, @c, @TotalCnt-(@c-1))
    end
    return @TS
end

return @String  
end
```

USAGE

```
update [YourTable] set fldToDelimit = dbo.SplitBy(fldToDelimit, '|')
```

HOPE THIS HELP YOU!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select

concat
(
concat(substring(comments, 1, 20), '|'),
concat(substring(comments, 21, 20), '|'),
concat(substring(comments, 41, 20), '|'),
concat(substring(comments, 61, 20), '|'),
concat(substring(comments, 81, 20), '|')
)

from
t
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad537/1

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure if this will not work if the comments has less than 100 character for example 20.

Comment: You can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine. One more question though, what if the size is huge? For e.g. 1000 or 2000

Comment: Then I would recommend you get the length of the comments string, and you write some stored procedure or some block (e.g. using a loop or some temporary tables) of SQL code which solves this more general version of your problem.

Comment: Hi! Please see my answer below.. It will parse your field up to the maximum capacity.